# Django : is it better to import variables from a settings.py file, or basic configuration file?

Tags: python, django, configuration, settings

I was wondering about whether it is better to import variables into your view from the settings.py file? or better to create a configuration file with the variables that are needed?

I tend to like to write configuration files for my Django applications, read, and import the variables from there when necessary. For example:

**.configrc**

```
[awesomeVariables]
someMagicNumber = 7
```

**views.py**

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
#Open and parse the file
config = SafeConfigParser()
config.read(pathToConfig)
#Get variable
magicNumber   = config.get('awesomeVariables', 'someMagicNumber'))
```

*However*, I've noticed some programmers prefer the following :

**settings.py**

```
SOME_MAGIC_NUMBER=7
```

**views.py**

```
import settings
magicNumber = settings.SOME_MAGIC_NUMBER
```

I was curious as to the pros and cons of the different methods? Can importing variables directly from your settings compromise the integrity of the architecture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a judgement call. Using the settings module is the "Django way", although you should do `from django.conf import settings; settings.MY_SETTING`, which will respect `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. But Django is just Python; there's nothing that will stop you from using `ConfigParser`. In the interest of having only one place where such things are defined, I'd recommend putting it in the Django settings file - but if you have a reason not to, don't.

Comment: +1, plus consider if you use the "Django way" it's easier to make settings that are the result of an expression, i.e. "someMagicNumber = someMagicFunction()" which you basically get for free. Using the "config file" approach would require extra work on your part to get the same functionality.

Comment: One reason not to might be if your code has substantial code which is not Django specific. For example, if you had added a Django front-end to a large simulation code, to web enable input, it might already have a configuratino system. It would probably be a mistake to incorporate that into `settings.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a config file is completely un-Django. Settings go in settings.py. Period. For app-specific settings, you simply set a default in your app and allow the user to override in their project's settings.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

SOME_MAGIC_NUMBER = settings.SOME_MAGIC_NUMBER if hasattr(settings, 'SOME_MAGIC_NUMBER') else 0
# Where `0` is the default value
```

Comment: *Settings go in settings.py. Period* Any justification for this statement? The OP is specifically asking for *reasons*. "Because I know it must" isn't really sufficient.

Comment: Let's see... justifications... no where in the Django docs *or* the Django codebase itself is the idea of "config" files ever even hinted about. However, settings is used by Django, Django contrib packages, and every Django app I've ever encountered.

Comment: Django wiki says there is no preffered config method: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings
Though I agree that django devs are used to settings.py so it's a safe default.

Answer (score 1):

There also an app for storing settings dynamically in db. Maybe you find it usefull .
[django-constance](https://github.com/comoga/django-constance)